# Subquery not working the way i want it to

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

This is my first ever post here on stackoverflow.

I would like to see what the min, average and max salary is per education level per marital_status.
I've tried this code but it only shows the same value for min, average and max for all the different education levels:

```
Select distinct education, (select min(convert(int, income))
                            from [dbo].[marketing_campaign] where marital_status = 'Married' and year_birth > 1980 and income <> 0) Min_Married,
                            (select avg(convert(int, income))
                            from [dbo].[marketing_campaign] where marital_status = 'Married' and year_birth > 1980 and income <> 0) Avg_Married,
                            (select max(convert(int, income))
                            from [dbo].[marketing_campaign] where marital_status = 'Married' and year_birth > 1980 and income <> 0) Max_Married,
                            (select min(convert(int, income))
                            from [dbo].[marketing_campaign] where marital_status = 'Single' and year_birth > 1980 and income <> 0) Min_Single,
                            (select avg(convert(int, income))
                            from [dbo].[marketing_campaign] where marital_status = 'Single' and year_birth > 1980 and income <> 0) Avg_Single,
                            (select max(convert(int, income))
                            from [dbo].[marketing_campaign] where marital_status = 'Single' and year_birth > 1980 and income <> 0) Max_Single,
                            (select min(convert(int, income))
                            from [dbo].[marketing_campaign] where marital_status = 'together' and year_birth > 1980 and income <> 0) Min_together,
                            (select avg(convert(int, income))
                            from [dbo].[marketing_campaign] where marital_status = 'together' and year_birth > 1980 and income <> 0) Avg_together,
                            (select max(convert(int, income))
                            from [dbo].[marketing_campaign] where marital_status = 'together' and year_birth > 1980 and income <> 0) Max_together
from [dbo].[marketing_campaign]
where  education in ('master', 'Graduation', 'phd', 'basic')
group by education
order by education desc
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no correlation with `education` in your sub-queries, neither is there any need for repeatedly using a sub-query when I suspect what you need is the following:

```
with i as (
    select education, 
        Iif(marital_status = 'Married' , Convert(int, income),0) Income_Married,
        Iif(marital_status = 'Single'  , Convert(int, income),0) Income_Single,
        Iif(marital_status = 'together', Convert(int, income),0) Income_Together,
    from dbo.marketing_campaign
    where education in ('master', 'Graduation', 'phd', 'basic')
    and year_birth > 1980 and income != 0
)
select education, 
    Min(Income_Married) Min_Married,
    Avg(Income_Married) Avg_Married,
    Max(Income_Married) Max_Married,
    Min(Income_Single) Min_Single,
    Avg(Income_Single) Avg_Single,
    Max(Income_Single) Max_Single,
    Min(Income_Together) Min_Together,
    Avg(Income_Together) Avg_Together,
    Max(Income_Together) Max_Together
from i
group by education
order by education desc;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. 
I realize now that i wasn't clear in my explanation/question.
The reason why i did a subquery is because i want to check for all the different marital status min, avg and max as columns. I.e. i i want 9 subqueries, min, avg and max for 'single', 'married' and 'together'.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are expecting- the above gives the same columns as your example query. If the above is not what you require then it would be helpful to supply some example data and show what your desired results are.

Comment: I've updated the post. 
With the code i've written the output gives me the same values for all different education levels. For example:
education Min_Married
PhD 7500
Master 7500
Graduation 7500
Basic 7500

Comment: @MartinNordinSundberg Based on your edited question I have revised above - there are a few ways to conditionally `case` the agregations, you can also use the essentially the same but more terse *inline if*, and separating the conditional case logic from the aggregations makes for a slightly cleaner (imho) approach.

Comment: Thank you so much Stu, the CTE version did the work!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this as follow. I tried to make the same environment as you describe in my DB, so hope this will help you.

```
SELECT   DISTINCT C.education,
         MIN(income) OVER(PARTITION BY education) AS MIN_Married, 
         AVG(income) OVER(PARTITION BY education) AS AVG_Married, 
         MAX(income) OVER(PARTITION BY education) AS MAX_Married 
FROM     [dbo].[marketing_campaign] C
WHERE    education IN ('master', 'Graduation', 'phd', 'basic')
         AND marital_status = 'Married'
         AND year_birth > 1980
ORDER BY education DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I realize now that i wasn't clear in my explanation/question. The reason why i did a subquery is because i want to check for all the different marital status min, avg and max as columns. I.e. i i want 9 subqueries, min, avg and max for 'single', 'married' and 'together'.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT education, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Married' AND year_birth > 1980 AND income <> 0) THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Min_Married,
       AVG(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Married' AND year_birth > 1980 AND income <> 0) THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Avg_Married,
       MAX(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Married' AND year_birth > 1980 AND income <> 0) THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END)  Max_Married,
       MIN(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Single' AND year_birth > 1980 AND income <> 0) THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Min_Single,
       AVG(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Single' AND year_birth > 1980 AND income <> 0) THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Avg_Single,
       MAX(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Single' AND year_birth > 1980 AND income <> 0) THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Max_Single,
       MIN(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'together' AND year_birth > 1980 AND income <> 0) THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Min_together,
       AVG(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'together' AND year_birth > 1980 AND income <> 0) THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Avg_together,
       MAX(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'together' AND year_birth > 1980 AND income <> 0) THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Max_together
FROM [dbo].[marketing_campaign]
WHERE education IN ('master', 'Graduation', 'phd', 'basic')
GROUP BY education
ORDER BY education DESC;
```

Or, move the common conditions in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT education, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Married' THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Min_Married,
       AVG(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Married' THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Avg_Married,
       MAX(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Married' THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END)  Max_Married,
       MIN(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Single' THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Min_Single,
       AVG(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Single' THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Avg_Single,
       MAX(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'Single' THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Max_Single,
       MIN(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'together' THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Min_together,
       AVG(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'together' THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Avg_together,
       MAX(CASE WHEN marital_status = 'together' THEN CONVERT(INT, income) END) Max_together
FROM [dbo].[marketing_campaign]
WHERE education IN ('master', 'Graduation', 'phd', 'basic')
  AND year_birth > 1980 AND income <> 0
GROUP BY education
ORDER BY education DESC;
```

Comment: @MartinNordinSundberg and it was posted before the answer that you accepted was edited.